# Memory reporting for Chrome application

Tags: memory, google-chrome-extension

We created a [Chrome application](http://beta.msgboy.com/) and we want to release it to the public soon.
Some of the testers reported a very **high memory usage**, so I checked on my very own Chrome.

When I check the 'Task Manager', I find out that the app we're creating consumes a lot f memory (about 300MB)!
This is quite worry some so I tried to check in details.

When going to `chrome://extensions/`, I see that the only active view is the background page. 
Using the heap profiler I found out that this background script *only* consumed about 20MB. 
This is obviously a lot, but far from the count.

Where is the missing memory to go from 20MB to 300MB?

When using `chrome://memory-redirect/`, I can see that, when the app was just started, the memory split is:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Resident | Shared  | Private  | Virtual  |
--------------------------------------------
| 36,864k  | 84,992k | 15,360k  | 839,680k |
--------------------------------------------
```

After running for a little while (6hours) it is:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Resident | Shared  | Private  | Virtual  |
--------------------------------------------
| 143,360k | 92,160k | 120,832k | 949,248k |
--------------------------------------------
```

Another finding earlier today.
Our background page is quite "small" with less than 20MB. This stays small overall, even though the global consumption of the app keeps increasing. We found out that this happens when we open new tabs from our application. The global consumption quickly adds up. We expected that it would go down when we close the tabs. This isn't the case. It goes down a bit, but more than 50% of the memory added up at that time stays in our app, when the tab is closed.

Here is a [little screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xdx3nNrWY_8) to provide details/help to anyone who wants to "see" things.

Comment: Do you see anything in chrome://memory?

Comment: @blahdiblah I see the pid of the extension, its memory (resident, shared and private)... but not much else :(

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Some comments, not a real solution here: **1)** You can get more "low level" details in chrome://tcmalloc/ **2)** Probably you want also to visit chrome://chrome-urls/ **3)** Test your application with Developer Tools **closed**, "sometimes" I have memory issues when they are open

Comment: @JuanMellado For some reason chrome://tcmalloc/ doesn't load :(.

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Hmmm... I'm using Chrome 18.0.1025.56 (dev channel) 1) Open a tab to chrome://tcmalloc/ 2) Open another tab to your page 3) Reload (F5) the first tab

Comment: On both Chrome 17.0.963.79 and Canary 19.0.1069.0, `chrome://tcmalloc/` shows `Error 300 (net::ERR_INVALID_URL): Unknown error.` :( It looks like the TCMalloc view is not available on Mac Os X!

Answer (score -1):

Is your extension communicating to any content scripts or just background pages?

When you took the heap snapshot, the number of MBs defined there doesn't resemble the total amount of memory your extension consumes. It only resembles how big your heap stats are.

Try taking heap snapshots like this:

1. Click on your Background page from the extension page to open the inspector.
2. Select the profiler tab
3. Take a Heap Snapshot once, wait till it finishes.
4. Play with your app a bit, to make sure your background page is doing some work.
5. Take another Heap Snapshot to record. Wait till it finishes.
6. On the bottom of the screen, there is a comparison dropdown box, so Instead of Summary, select Comparison.
7. Now analyze your data, to see what has been allocated, and freed.

You should see some inconsistencies since leaks are happening. I assume it isn't a DOM leak because your in a background page (unless your injecting elements), if so check the HTML items in your summary to see how many were created.

Comment: The app does have content scripts indeed. I will try to do what you ask, but that doesn't answer where the misses 280MB are, does it?

Comment: It was leaking somewhere, try running the heap for a bit longer and use your app completely (extensively) and run it again. Compare the heaps and see which function consumes alot of cycles. Hopefully you will see the big jump in allocations.

Comment: Ive got an extension that has a popup (page for the webapp version) that crawls pages and eats memory (still not sure why exactly, I dont know how to use the heap profiler) and one odd thing it does is it seems to pass the memory usage to the background page even tho the background page has nothing in it, nothing! (after you close the tab/popup the memory usage doesnt go away)?...maybe your having the same sort of problem.  Sorry I have no idea why and cant help, but thought Id mention it.

Comment: @MohamedMansour I did exactly what you recommanded, and well, even though the memory grew a bit (about 0.11MB), the "comparison" view doesn't really show anything meaningful, and obviously nothing near 280MB. Where are those?

Comment: @PAEz We do have web apps notifications, but that doesn't seem to be the issue :(

Comment: @MohamedMansour Any idea of where that memory could be?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Are you setting any function intervals?

Comment: @jjNford what do you call function intervals? Timeouts?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux setInterval(time, function)

Comment: @jjNford we do use them, but we make sure they're either canceled of fired.

Comment: @jjNford just curious if a resource intensive functions interval is somehow getting set multiple time and never cancelled.  Have you tried logging at the beginning of each function call to check this.  Maybe an interval is being set more than once and firing often.